# pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed - singly linked list

Tags: c, nodes

I'm trying to create a simple singly linked list. Previously, I successfully did this with no errors, however now I encounter an error. I suspect that there is some kind of problem with memory allocation because of the `if` statement in line 23.

What I've tried:

1. I used typecasting in all of my declarations even though it is not necessary in C.
2. I removed the `if` statement and I still encountered the errors.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int value;
    struct Product *next;

} Product;

int main()
{
    int user_choice;
    Product *head;

    head = malloc(sizeof(Product));
    head->next = NULL;
    head->value = 5;

    printf("\n Do you want to add a new node (0 for no, 1 for yes)? \n");
    scanf("%d", &user_choice);

    if (user_choice == 1) // line 23
    {
        head->next = malloc(sizeof(Product));

        if (!head->next)
            printf("\n Memory allocation failed! \n");

        head->next->next = NULL; // 1st error 

        printf("\n Enter a value: \n");

        int value;
        scanf("%d", &value);

        head->next->value = value; // 2nd error
    }

    free(head);
    free(head->next);
}
```

Comment: What makes you suspect line 23? Post the error message you are getting.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Because the program might not know whether or not to allocate memory but upon further inspection that was a wrong thought of mine. Everything above the ```if``` statement works perfect. Here's the error message **pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed**

Comment: If your compiler complains about an incomplete *class* type, then you must be compiling with a C++ compiler, or otherwise as if your code were C++.  That does not appear to be the underlying cause of the problem you ask about, but it could be ***a*** problem.  C and C++ have a common subset, but neither is fully compatible with the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
typedef struct
{
} Product;
```

Declares a type alias called `Product` for an *unnamed* struct - however you need a *named*  struct for your forward declaration `struct Product *next;`, otherwise the compiler cannot determine which definition it belongs to.

The simplest solution is to give the struct a name:

```
typedef struct Product
{
    int value;
    struct Product *next;
} Product;
```