# Getting Error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct type'

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile some functions with a draft main() and when I try to compile I get 3 errors saying :dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct InfoSession', 'struct TabNode', 'struct SiteNode' respectively on the lines  `SessionPtr->FirstTab = TabPtr;` 
`TabPtr->PrevTab = NULL;` `SitePtr->PrevSite = NULL;` inside the SessionNew function. I've searched but couldn't find anything to help me.
Any ideas on how to fix this error?
Thanks in advance.

```
typedef struct TabNode *TabNodePtr;
typedef struct SiteNode *SiteNodePtr;
typedef struct InfoSession *InfoSessionPtr;

typedef struct {
    TabNodePtr FirstTab;
    TabNodePtr LastTab;
    TabNodePtr CurrTab;
    TabNodePtr AuxTab;
    char*     OpeningAddress;
} InfoSession;

typedef struct {
    TabNodePtr PrevTab, NextTab;
    SiteNodePtr FirstSite;
    SiteNodePtr CurrSite;
} TabNode;

typedef struct {
    SiteNodePtr PrevSite, NextSite;
    TabNodePtr UpTab;
    char *Address;
} SiteNode;


InfoSessionPtr SessionNew(char *OpeningAddress){
    InfoSessionPtr SessionPtr;
    TabNodePtr TabPtr;
    SiteNodePtr SitePtr;

    SessionPtr = malloc(sizeof(InfoSession));
    if (SessionPtr == NULL){
      printf("Not enough space to allocate memory for InfoSession\n");
      exit(0);
    }

    TabPtr = malloc(sizeof(TabNode));
    if (TabPtr == NULL){
      printf("Not enough space to allocate memory for first tab\n");
      exit(0);
    }

    SitePtr = malloc(sizeof(SiteNode));
    if (SitePtr == NULL){
      printf("Not enough space to allocate memory for first site\n");
      exit(0);
    }

    SessionPtr->FirstTab = TabPtr;
    SessionPtr->LastTab = TabPtr;
    SessionPtr->CurrTab = TabPtr;
    SessionPtr->AuxTab = NULL;

    TabPtr->PrevTab = NULL;
    TabPtr->NextTab = NULL;
    TabPtr->FirstSite = SitePtr;
    TabPtr->CurrSite = SitePtr;

    SitePtr->PrevSite = NULL;
    SitePtr->NextSite = NULL;
    SitePtr->UpTab = TabPtr;
    SitePtr->Address = OpeningAddress;
    return SessionPtr;
}
```

Comment: `struct TabNode` and `typedef struct {} TabNode` are two different things, see also my answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55678436/2878796

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) for just this reason.

Comment: Additionally `SitePtr = malloc(sizeof(SiteNode));` creates a memory-leak.